# How to wait for end of function till go to next code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following code to add a content and after that, work with this new added content.

For this, its necessary to wait, till the content is sucessfully added before i try to work with this.

I read something about .done or .when and timeouts, but i could not understand this also i think its really complicate - so i ask for help to find the simplest way, to wait for adding the new content, before i go on in the script.

This is my code

```
function create_content(){ $('#element').html('<div>my new content</div>'); }

if($('#element div').length<=0){ create_content(); }

$('#element div').addClass('add-this-to-new-content');
```

Thanks a lot, for explaining how it should be!

Comment: try using setTimeout function. Put a timeout of a few seconds to the  $('#element div').addClass('add-this-to-new-content'); So it will wait for the time you give.

Comment: i've read something about it, but i dont understand it, could you make me a small example based on my code, that i could understand how it should work?

Comment: addClass(){
  $('#element div').addClass('add-this-to-new-content');
}
setTimout(function(){addClass()},5000);

Comment: Jquery' HTML() method ain't asynchronous nor it takes time to complete its operations. Why are not you doing what you want in a sequential manner?

Answer (score 1):

Use a promise and inside that promise resolve function delegate the task of adding a new html and return the length in the resolve. Now you can use `then` and check for value

```js
function create_content() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $('#element').html('<div>my new content</div>');
    resolve($('#element div').length)

  })
}

create_content().then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  if (data <= 0) {
    create_content()
  } else {
    $('#element div').addClass('add-this-to-new-content');
  }


})
```

```css
.add-this-to-new-content {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
    function create_content_new(){ $('#element').html('<div>my new content</div>'); console.log('done_new'); return true; }

if($('#element div').length<=0){ var test = create_content_new(); }
console.log('call');
$('#element div').addClass('add-this-to-new-content');
```

Basically return the value from the function and check it by assigning to a variable when calling function, it should wait until the function completes the execution.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of the code is **JUST** to add a class .. you can use something like this

```js
function create_content(NewClass){
  $('#element').html('<div>my new content</div>').find("> div").addClass(NewClass);
}

if($('#element div').length<=0){ 
  create_content('add-this-to-new-content'); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to accomplish what you need here, I would suggest you to differentiate between JavaScript and jquery code you have written, that way it will be easier to understand the methods (like .then,.when ..etc)

Check the complete separation of JQuery/Javascript in the below Git Repo, hope you should be able to understand it completely.

GIT Repo
https://github.com/helloritesh000/how-to-wait-for-end-of-function-till-go-to-next-code

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="element">

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if($('#element div').length<=0){ 
        create_content(callback_function); 
    }

    function create_content(callback){ 
        $('#element').html('<div>my new content</div>'); 
        callback();
    }

    function callback_function()
    {
        $('#element div').addClass('add-this-to-new-content');
    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```